# Change domain name in a WordPress website with Divi builder

Tags: wordpress

I have a Wordpress website hosted under a development domain name, and it is using the Divi Builder plugin.

When I try to move it to its production domain name, there is a javascript file needed by Divi Builder that still has adherence to its previous environment, and I cannot figure out where such configuration is stored.

Here are the environment details :

**Dev env :**

```
URL : http://dev.domain.tld
Physical : /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/dev.domain.tld
```

**Prod env :**

```
URL : https://domain.tld
Physical : /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/www.domain.tld
```

**Error :**

Divi builder `common.js` file is loaded through this weird path :
`https://domain.tld/wp-content/plugins/var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/dev.domain.tld/wp-content/plugins/divi-builder/core/admin/js/common.js?ver=3.9`

That means that the path starts with the **new domain**, but then shows adherence to the **previous physical path**.

This file is trying to be loaded straight from the home page, even when logged off. When logging on and editing pages/posts, the Divi Builder is partly loaded, which means partly broken (and non functional) because of the same loading paths errors.

So far, I only changed 2 records in the database, the 2 first lines of the wp_options table, where the canonical domain name is defined.

In a first attempt, I had used the Velvet plugin to replace all domain occurences, and in the second attempt, I chose to do it only once the Divi Builder issue is solved.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found THE very record where the physical path of Divi Builder is stored.
It is in `wp_content` table, where the `option_name` is `_site_transient_et_core_path`.
There is the path clearly defined, and it should be updated.

Comment: Do you may mean `wp_options` instead of `wp_content` table?